# Calling function from different file in PowerShell

Tags: function, powershell, syntax

I've done lot of Googleing but have not found a solution to my problem.
I'm rebuilding a tool we have at work for our ServiceDesk but have run in to a problem.

I use menus and submenus with a switch-block.
The menues themself are functions within the same file. However apart from the "numbering" of submenus I also have a few other commands set as functions that I want to work as well.
I've tried declaring functions above the switch in the same document and also tried using a differet file to call on these functions but I can't make it work.

```
Function sys
{
    Param (
    [string]$computer
    )
    systeminfo /s $computer
}

# Visa huvudmeny
Function ShowMenu
{
 
    Write-Host "

Kommandon:                                                                                                                   
1                      - Alternativ för datorer                                                           
2                      - Alternativ för användare                                                
3                      - Övriga alternativ                                                    
"
}
 
# Visa Datorer-meny
Function subComputer
{
    Write-Host "
Kommandon:                                                                                                                   
rem [datornamn]    - se vem som är inloggad, tryck på y för att koppla upp dig   
rdp [datornamn]    - Starta rdp och koppla upp mot dator                         
rc [datornamn]     - mappa upp användarens dator                                                   
mac [datornamn]    - hämta datorns MAC-adress                                          sys [datornamn]    - se information om datorn/systemet                                
update [datornamn] - kör GPUpdate /force på användarens FMAP                                  
reboot [datornamn] - Starta om användarens FMAP                                                
ping [datornamn]   - pinga användares dator                                                        
pingt [datornamn]  - pinga användares dator (pingsnurra), avbryt med Ctrl-C           
q                  - tillbaka till huvudmenyn                           
"
 
}
 
# Visa Användare-meny
Function subUser
{
    Write-Host "
Kommandon:                                                                                                                                                                 
password           - starta lösenordsgeneratorn                                                    
q                  - tillbaka till huvudmenyn                                            
 
"
}
 
# Visa Övrigt-meny
Function subMisc
{
    Write-Host "

Kommandon:                                                                                                                   
remlog             - Visa loggfilen för rem                                      
rdplog             - Visa loggfilen för rdp                                      
archive            - Arkivera loggfilerna                                                                                              
gw                 - öppna fönstret för att kunna pinga gateway                       
password           - starta lösenordsgeneratorn                                                    
q                  - tillbaka till huvudmenyn                                            
"
} 


do
{
    Clear-Host
    ShowMenu
    $menuItem = Read-Host
    switch($menuItem)
    {
        "1"
        {
        
            do{
                Clear-Host
                subComputer
                $subComputer = Read-Host
                switch($subComputer)
                {
                    "1"{subComputer}
                    "2"{subUser}
                    "3"{subMisc}
                }
            }
            until ($subComputer -eq "q")
        }
        "2"
        {
        
            do{
                Clear-Host
                subUser
                $subUser = Read-Host
                switch($subUser)
                {
                    "1"{subComputer}
                    "2"{subUser}
                    "3"{subMisc}
                }
            }
            until ($subUser -eq "q")
        }
        "3"
        {
        
            do{
                Clear-Host
                subMisc
                $subMisc = Read-Host
                switch($subMisc)
                {
                    "1"{subComputer}
                    "2"{subUser}
                    "3"{subMisc}
                }
            }
            until ($subMisc -eq "q")
        }
        default{. 'C:\Temp\SDV 4.2 Lite\WindowsPowerShell\moduler\func.ps1'}
    }
}
until ($menuItem -eq "q")
```

Right now I have placed the external functionfile within the default but that does not work. I don't know where to put it to make it call my other functions. It accepts 1, 2, 3 and q with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to dot-source the `func.ps1` file *before* your code reaches the point where it needs to invoke the functions - doing it *before* entering the loop is probably what you want here:

```
# dot-source function definitions, discard any output from the script itself
$null = . 'C:\Temp\SDV 4.2 Lite\WindowsPowerShell\moduler\func.ps1'

do
{
  # ...
}until($menuItem -eq "q")
```

Comment: No, unfortunately that doesn't seem to work at all. It loads the menus (functions) `showMenu` for example. I put a function directly in the script again. Does nothing. As soon as the loop is entered all other commands just stop working exept for 1, 2, 3 and q.
Do I need to use the variable somewhere in the script or is it just used as a placeholder?

Comment: "It loads the menus (functions) showMenu for example." - so it works? I'm confused as to which part _isn't_ working? It's also unclear why you nest the same menu options (eg. I can get `subUser` to execute by either picking `2` in the main menu, or by picking `1` and then `2` in the submenu)?

Comment: Ok. I get I was a little unclear. There is one menu `showMenu` that has three sub-menus `subComputer`, `subUser` and `subMisc`. These are declared as functions and these work inside the loop. Inside the submenus are other commands. The command "password" should call on the function with the same name but it does not. While not in the loop it executes as it should but while in the loop it does not. I am confused by why it does not work in the loop. Nothing happen when I type password and hit enter. It just clears the prompt, leaving it empty.

Comment: @JoakimHellström Please take a look at the code you've posted in your question - `password` is nowhere to be found - you just keep calling `sub*` in the sub-menus?

Comment: Ok. I have updated the code. Added the function `sys` as well as the menus I use. Sorry for the formatting. The command `sys` can be found under the menu choise labeled as "1".

Comment: @JoakimHellström You're still not _calling_ `sys` anywhere?